# Serial Thread Confinement

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to implement serial thread confinement in java. I have created a reference of a mutable object  in Thread A's run method . Now I want to hand off the object to Thread B in such a way that only Thread B has mutual exclusive  to the object and sees the modification done to the object made by A(this I can make sure by safely publishing it), but How can  I assure that only Thread B has access to the object and none other thread has? Book says it can be done using  Blocking Queue with little more effort .Can any one help me in implementing this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let thread A put the object on a BlockingQueue and thread B take it off. In this case a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) - which has no internal capacity to store objects - would be a good candidate because you only need to exchange one object. This is slightly easier than an Exchanger because you need only exchange an object in one direction. It's Javadoc even mentions that "An Exchanger may be viewed as a bidirectional form of a SynchronousQueue".

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) shared between two threads. One thread (thread B) will send null and other (thread A) will send the required object. So the thread A will safely publish the object to thread B.